Strict Comparison in Pandas
I have a dataframe that looks like this
[Median Income, Group]
[$0, Male:Age 0-18]
[$37,000, Male]


when I use
df = df[df['Group'].eq('Male')]
I end up getting all columns containing the string 'Male' instead of a string that is strictly 'Male'.
Is there anyway to make a strict  comparison so that I only pull the 'Male' row?

Your input is not reproducible, please [edit] your question with the output of df.head().to_dict('tight'). Also read [ask] and [mre].

To get a substring match you need df[df['Group'].str.contains('Male')], df[df['Group'].eq('Male')] should already give you a strict match.

The command you used gives me only the row that contains "Male". Not sure why it works differently for you. But you probably should use loc for strict comparisons like so: df.loc[df.Group == "Male", :]
